# Create-react-app not working with installed version of npm

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm

I have:
Installed latest version of Node (12.19.0) and npm (6.14.8)

```
npm uninstall -g create-react-app
npm install -g create-react-app

npx create-react-app todo-app.
```

The process freezes in this spot (see image).[problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xkCxe.png)

Running catalina 10.15.7

Answer (score 0):

just update your npm package by installing the latest version of npm from its official website.

Comment: I already installed the most recent version of npm from the official website "npm (6.14.8)"